# One to many join to last modified record in the most efficient way

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, one-to-many

I realise that variations of this question have been asked before but I'd like to know the most efficient solution to my particular issue.

I have two tables...

**Event** (event_id, customer_email...)

**Customer** (customer_email, last_modified...)

I'm joining these two tables and only want the customer with the greatest last_modified date. The customer table is absolutely huge so was wondering the best way to go about this.

Comment: then this is more about how your data is indexed than just the query....  I can show you a query but the performance may be bad without properly indexed

Comment: @t-mckeown - hi thanks for the reply. Could you show me the query anyway and I can test it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Setting aside indices, this is the query you could use:

```
SELECT <columns you want>
FROM Event AS E
JOIN Customer AS C
  ON C.Customer_Email = E.Customer_Email
JOIN ( SELECT C1.Customer_Email, MAX(C1.Last_Modified) AS LastModified
       FROM Customer AS C1
       GROUP BY C1.Customer_Email
) AS C2
ON C2.Customer_Email = C.Customer_Email
AND C2.LastModified = C.Last_Modified
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number`

```
select * 
from 
(
select *, Row_number() over (partition by Event_ID order by Last_Modified desc) rn
from Event 
    inner join Customer 
    on Event.Customer_Email = Customer.Customer_Email
) v
where rn = 1
```